# VBA Function not Returning Value

Tags: vba, excel, function

I have a VBA code that's designed to search a CSV String and add Carriage Returns where they should exist. I've split it up into two seperate functions - one to search the string and put the index of where the CRs should go into an array and a second function to actually add the CRs.

The issue I'm running into is that the value in the immediate window/in the watch window for the functions is correct within the function itself, but it assigns the result variable a blank string.

```
'*****************Import CSV**********************
'Took this straight off the internet because it was reading Jet.com files as one single line
'
Sub ImportCSVFile(filepath As String)

    .....
    line = SearchString(line, "SALE")
    .....

End Sub

'****************Search String***************************
    'This is search the string for something - It will then call a function to insert carriage returns

Function SearchString(source As String, target As String) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim myArray() As Variant

Dim resultString As String

Do
    i = i + 1
    If Mid(source, i, Len(target)) = target Then
        ReDim Preserve myArray(k)
        myArray(k) = i
        k = k + 1
    End If
DoEvents
Loop Until i = Len(source)

resultString = addCarriageReturns(source, myArray) 'resultString here is assigned a blank string
SearchString = resultString

End Function

'***************Add Carraige Returns**************************
'Cycle through the indices held in the array and place carriage returns into the string


Function addCarriageReturns(source As String, myArray As Variant) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim resultString As String

resultString = source

For i = 0 To UBound(myArray, 1)
    resultString = Left(resultString, myArray(i) + i) & Chr(13) & Right(resultString, Len(resultString) - myArray(i) + i)
Next i

addCarraigeReturns = resultString 'The value of addCarriageReturn is correct in the immediate window here

End Function
```

[In the function the value is not blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2cqa.png)
[...but when it passes it back, it says the value is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ1Ff.png)

Comment: Check your spelling:  addCarriageReturns vs addCarraigeReturns

Comment: Turn on Option Explicit

Comment: @GordonBell the spelling was it. Thanks.

Comment: Save yourself the headaches, and never do VBA without "Option Explicit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just curious, why do you want separate functions like this?

Can you just use:

```
line = Replace(line, "SALE", "SALE" & Chr(13))
```

Comment: Because apparently I'm a masochist and do things the harder way. :)  I forgot that replace isn't destructive to the rest of the string, but only affects the part you specify.

Comment: Not to worry, happens to all of us. :)